# autocomplete not working in

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am not sure what mistake I have done but autocomplete of my jquery-ui is not working basically I put debugger and checked it seems autocomplete call it self not triggered. it is triggered only if I refresh the page please help me out here

```js
$(function() {
$(".autoComplete").autocomplete({
  source:function(reuqest,response){
   $.get({
    url:"/organization/suggestion",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:{
     q:request.term
    },
    success:function(data){
     response(data);
    }
   })
  }
 })
});
```

```html
<div id="ShowTextOrIdFieldBox"><input type="text" id="searchByText" name="searchByText" placeholder="enter name" class="autoComplete"></div>
```

and one more thing this input box I am populating using jquery based on user input jquery for this

```js
function showTextOrIdField(){
 var orgType=$('#searchByLabel option:selected').val();
 if(orgType=='searchByIdOption'){
  $("#searchByText").remove();
  
  $("ShowTextOrIdFieldBox")
  .addClass("col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12");
  
   $("<input type='text' value='' />")
      .attr("id", "searchById")
      .attr("name", "searchById")
      .attr("placeholder","enter id")
      .appendTo("#ShowTextOrIdFieldBox");
 }else if(orgType=='searchByTextOption'){
  $("#searchByOrgId").remove();
  
  $("ShowTextOrIdFieldBox")
  .addClass("col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12");
  
   $("<input type='text'  />")
      .attr("id", "searchByText")
      .attr("name", "searchByText")
      .attr("placeholder","enter name")
      .addClass("autoComplete")
      .appendTo("#ShowTextOrIdFieldBox");
 }
}
```

Comment: i think you have forgotten to put reference of jQuery file on your page.

Comment: I checked it jquery-ui.js and corresponding css is present

Comment: Add jquery reference on your page head. Check this url - https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/ . See under "Jquery - 3.x snippet:".

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by adding this cdn into my jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.js"></script>
```

and one more thing it's not working if I populate my text box dynamically. I don;t the reason please let me know if you know the reason